# java.lang.StackOverflowError When updating entity with many to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have 3 entities, `Employee`, `Shop` and `EmployeeShop` which is the link entity for `Employee` and `Shop`.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_shops")
class EmployeeShop(

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    var employee: Employee? = null,

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    var shop: Shop? = null

) : Serializable {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) {
            return true
        }
        if (other == null || javaClass != other.javaClass) {
            return false
        }
        other as EmployeeShop
        return Objects.equals(employee, other.employee) &&
            Objects.equals(shop, other.shop)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return Objects.hash(employee, shop)
    }
}
```

The Employee

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
class Employee(

    @Id
    var id: Int? = null,

    var userName: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var shops: MutableList<EmployeeShop> = mutableListOf()

) {
  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) {
        return true
    }
    if (other == null || javaClass != other.javaClass) {
        return false
    }
    other as Employee
    return Objects.equals(userName, other.userName) &&
        Objects.equals(email, other.email)
  }

  override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return Objects.hash(userName, email)
  }
}
```

And the Shop

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "shops")
class Shop(

    @Id
    var id: Int? = null,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var users: MutableList<EmployeeShop> = mutableListOf(),

) {
  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) {
        return true
    }
    if (other == null || javaClass != other.javaClass) {
        return false
    }
    other as Shop
    return Objects.equals(id, other.id)
  }

  override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return Objects.hash(id)
  }
}
```

The `EmployeeRepository` is something like this

```kotlin
interface EmployeeRepository: CrudRepository<Employee, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.shops WHERE e.id = :id")
    override fun findById(id: String): Optional<Employee>
}
```

The reason I override this is to add `LEFT JOIN FETCH` in order to avoid `LazyInitializationException`

To return from the API, I transform the `Employee` to `EmployeeDto`

```kotlin
fun getDto(entity: Employee): EmployeeDto {
    return EmployeeDto(
        userName = entity.userName,
        email = entity.email
        shops = entity.shops.map { IdAndNameDto(it.shop?.id?.toString().orEmpty(), it.shop?.name.orEmpty()) }
    )
}

class IdAndNameDto(val id: String = "", val name: String = "")

class EmployeeDto(
    val userName: String,
    val email: String,
    val shops: List<IdAndNameDto>?
)
```

When I use the repository to **update** the `Employee`

```kotlin
employeeRepo.save(employee)
```

The `save` is from `CrudRepository` ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-)). In here the `save` should return an instance of `Employee`.

I get the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:49) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:269) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:751) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:623) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabledFor(SLF4JLogger.java:213) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabled(SLF4JLogger.java:121) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.isEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1505) ~[log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger.isEnabled(Log4j2Logger.java:46) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:98) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.isTraceEnabled(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:54) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:695) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:878) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2410) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:695) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:878) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2410) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
...
```

The rest of the stack trace is just repeating of these few lines which you can also see from the above stacktrace

```
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:695) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:878) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2410) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
```

But I don't have any error when I try to **create** an Employee with the same `save` method.

Also, this only happens if the employee entity contains an non-empty `shops` object. If the `shop` is empty, which means the `Employee` I got using `findById` doesn't have any record in the `EmployeeShop` link table, then the update also don't any error.

I'm still new to JPA, so my suspect is that the way I declared those Entities, like how I use annotations, is not correct. But I'm not sure where is the problem.

Does anyone know why I got the StackOverflow error?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? StackOverflows normally come with tons of repeating rows in the call stack.

Comment: Add controller and service and repository code also

Comment: Are you returning any response?

Comment: @JensSchauder that's not the full stack trace. But the rest are just repeating those lines. I've updated the description.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh I added the kind of repository I use. I'm using WebFlux, and for this call it's not using any @Service. It's just a @Component which uses the `EmployeeRepository` directly.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh No it never return any response. The stacktrace showed in the terminal, and the Postman is still waiting for response.

Comment: Can you add the codes where you return the response and which object are you return?

Comment: Actually problem is after returning so those code is necessary. Are you returning `employee` ?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh The API call will return an `EmployeeDto` object which is transformed from an `Employee`. But when I debug, the StackOverflow error happens during the `save` and it never comes out to the next line. I added more information above about another thing I noticed.

Comment: Add your EmployeeDto class also and code where you transformed.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh Sure! I added some code to describe the transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally solved this by using the "trying-everything-I-can" approach.

1. I removed the `EmployeeShop` entity class.
2. In the `Employee` class, I made this change.

   ```
   // old
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
   var shops: MutableList<EmployeeShop> = mutableListOf()

   // new
   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
       name = "employee_shops",
       joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")],
       inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")]
   )
   var shops: MutableSet<Shop> = mutableSetOf()
   ```
3. And in the `Shop` class

   ```
   // old
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
   var users: MutableList<EmployeeShop> = mutableListOf()

   // new
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shops")
   var users: MutableSet<Employee> = mutableSetOf()
   ```

Then the exception was gone and the app was back to work again. My Hibernate/JPA knowledge is not adequate to explain why this works. But if anyone has the same issue, this may be the solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't spot any obvious mistake on your side, and judging from the comments others can't either.

So you have two things that you can/should do:

1. Simplify the example:

   - Remove code (like, equals, hashcode, properties) to get a minimal example and thereby also an idea what might trigger this problem.
   - Try to convert it to Java, although I expect that this will make the problem disappear, but that is just a guess.
   - Reproduce it with Hibernate directly, without Spring Data.
2. set a breakpoint at the location that gets repeated over and over again in the stack trace. Use the debugger to inspect values and step through the code, often this will give you at least a rough idea what is going wrong and it might therefore give you a idea for a work around.
3. If you still haven't found a bug, use the reproducer you created in step one a bug with Hibernate or Spring Data, depending on your findings in step one.